# How to find a property in a nested object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to figure out how to extract result based on an object property value that is inside another object e.g

```
{
   title: 'The Book',
   author: {
      name: 'Merlin Bridge',
      category: 'Fiction'
   }
}
```

Here are my tests:

```
  // this works
  const test1 = _.find(existingBooks, {
    title: uploadedBooks[i].title,
  });

  // this doesn't work and returns nothing
  const test2 = _.find(existingBooks, {
    'author.name': uploadedBooks[i].author.name,
  });
```

I want to get the result wherein the `author.name` is the identifier. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using Lodash/Underscore `find`, I took the liberty to also use the `get` helper. Please find below an answer which should help you.

```js
const books = [{
    title: 'The Book',
    author: {
      name: 'Merlin Bridge',
      category: 'Fiction'
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Another Book',
    author: {
      name: 'Merlin Window',
      category: 'Science'
    }
  }
];
const uploadedBooks = [{
    title: 'Another Book',
    author: {
      name: 'Merlin Window',
      category: 'Science'
    }
  }];
const i = 0;
const foundBook = _.find(books, (book, index) => {
  return _.get(book, 'author.name') === _.get(uploadedBooks, [i, 'author', 'name'])
});
console.log(foundBook);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Use below code to iterate your json object.

```js
var myObj = {
   title: 'The Book',
   author: {
      name: 'Merlin Bridge',
      category: 'Fiction'
   }
} 
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj[key]));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It also worked. However, I went ahead with ` existingBooks.find((book) => {
        const { author: { name } } = book;
        return name === uploadedBooks[i].author.name;
      });` and did not use lodash for this after finding out about javascript's `find` :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript objects.

Assuming you are looping an array and not an object:

```
var a = _.map(existingBooksArray, function(existingBook) {
    return {[existingBook.author.name]: existingBook.title}
});
```

Result of a:

```
[
    {
        Merlin Bridge: "The Book"
    }
]
```

Comment: @ thanks, this solution also worked but my use-case is more of find than map since I'm not transforming anything. :) https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c

Answer (score 1):

use .key method

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
console.log(myObj[key]);});
```

```js
var myObj = {
   title: 'The Book',
   author: {
      name: 'Merlin Bridge',
      category: 'Fiction'
   }
} 

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj[key]));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myObj = {
   title: 'The Book',
   author: {
      name: 'Merlin Bridge',
      category: 'Fiction'
   }
} 
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj[key]));
  });
```